# Jquery don't focus in disqus div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, disqus

I use disqus in my news site for comments, i put disqus div as `display:none`, i want that the user have to do click in a button for show and hide this div.

I did a script in jQuery doing toggle in this button, and I can hide and show the div, but when it shows, does not focus on the div, but this is where the button.

This is not useful since pressing the button should take the user to the section where comment, but does not.

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.gn-icon-bubble').attr("href","#foot").click(function(){
            $('.disqus_thread').toggle('swing');
         });
});
```

`.gn-icon-bubble` is the button and as you know, `.disqus-thread` is the div's class; `#foot` is my anchor, are in the main page's footer, but still don't works.

I've tried using anchors, but gives the same, still focus comments. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Event Delegation` for dynamically change element ,use `preventDefault` to stop default action

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.gn-icon-bubble').attr("href","#foot");
    $(document).on("click", ".gn-icon-bubble[href=#foot]" , function(event){
              // event.preventDefault(); If you want to stop default anchor tag click action 
                $('.disqus_thread').toggle('swing');
             });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i have to verify this and comment here the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.gn-icon-bubble').click(function() { 
   $('.disqus_thread').toggle('swing',function() {
     $('#foot').focus();
    });
    return false;
 });
```